# Bad performance with db queries in MVC

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, performance

I've setup an ASP.NET MVC application and connected it to a database through azure. In this I have a trafficlog table that contains over 1M entries which ofcourse takes its toll when you try to open it in a view - so I implemented paging.

This is the controller function i use to get the entries:

```
    public ActionResult Index(int startIndex){
        var trafficlog = db.TrafficLog.OrderByDescending(t => t.time).Skip(startIndex).Take(100);
        return View(trafficlog.ToList());
    }
```

Unfortunately this is slow as hell, and times out before returning the entries.

Why is this an issue? I had assumed that only 100 items would be requested from the database, which would make performance pretty swift, but it seems like it still gets all the entries.

using SQL server explorer and contacting the database directly, I get a near instant response, so I know there's no issue with the SQL server.

Comment: Use profiler to capture the SQL query that is beeing executed and execute that manually in Management Studio.

Comment: which ORM are you using?

Comment: Add trafficlog to the watch and you will see the entire SQL statement that will be ran against you db.

Comment: I am using entity framework in this instance

Comment: Sounds to me like your time column needs indexing have you check that yet?

Comment: Like JodyT said you really need to capture the query using Sql Profiler to see what is actually being sent to Sql Server from EF. Once you have that then you can look at the query plan in the Management Studio to see if there is anything odd that would cause that query to execute slower than the one you mention executing manually in Management Studio. If you google How To use Sql Profiler you will get a plethora of results.

Comment: @heymega you were absolutely correct. I'm still unable to index the time column based on my inexperience working with azure databases. But changing the sort order to sort by my primary key instead, provided me with much greater performance and the same functionality. Could you make a new Post on the thread so I can flag it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are missing an index on the `time` column. Check if you have the index, if not add the index.

Comment: Wouldn't that affect the SQL query directly as well?